# Programmable filter using Paraview

Tags: python, filter, vtk, paraview, openfoam

I have a surface with field values (.vtk), which is an output of an openfoam postprocessing (I have made it using a cutting plane on my geometry). I need to calculate the average field value on the surface and I don't know how to do it.

I was trying to do it using the programmable filter in paraview, but I couldn't. I have found some examples on how to use the tool here https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter, but I still don't know how to get the cell areas, and how to average the integral. Can somebody provide me a useful script to compute an average field? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to ask on https://discourse.paraview.org

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Integrate Variables" filter of ParaView. The output is a table that you can export to csv. By dividing the integrated values by the area, which is also reported in the table, you'll get the average values.

Comment: Using Integrate Variables, I get a table with: point values, cell values and field values. The first one gives me a unique value (maybe average?), the second one gives me the area, and the third one nothing. I have checked and the first value is not the average weighted by area, but it can be the simple average. And I never get an integral value.

Comment: @FedericoCaccia It appears to work for me. I've just opened a 3D results vtk file, applied a "Slice" filter to obtain a surface view, and applied "Integrate Variables" filter to this view to get the results table. The table contains as columns: Area, U, epsilon, k, nut, and p, taking values that are reasonable area integrals of these magnitudes.